# Elixir Absinthe input_object

Tags: elixir, absinthe

Why input_object in Elixir Absinthe is not working?

like

```
   input_object :vehicle_detail do
    field :registrationNo, :string
    field :imageUrl, :string
   end

  mutation do
    field :create_user, type: :user do
        arg :vehicle_details, :vehicle_detail

        resolve &Resolver.create_employee/2
    end
  end
```

I tried but it is throwing errors for the following payload

```
mutation() {
  employee: createEmployee(vehicleDetails: {
      registrationNo: "AP03EY0096",
      imageUrl: "http://sample.example.com"
  }) {
    id
  }
}
```

Errors

```
In field \"vehicleDetails\": Expected type \"VehicleDetail\", found $vehicleDetails.\nIn field \"imageUrl\": Unknown field.\nIn field \"registrationNo\": Unknown field.",
```

Comment: There is a typo in `intput_object`, intended?

Comment: Got the reason for the error.

intput_object - :vehicle_detail is having camel case field names. After changing to snake case it worked.

Comment: @JonasDellinger thanks updated the question and it is just a typo but the actual code has no typo.

Answer (score 2):

please try to use atoms in snake case for input object definition:

```
  input_object :vehicle_detail do
    field(:registration_no, :string)
    field(:image_url, :string)
  end
```